# Dynamic Form with initial values

Tags: reactjs, antd

Sorry for my english.

Like in this example

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-lichterman-br63z?file=/index.js

Form.List is rendering the Array of "Fields" which initally is empty.

I would like to put my own array to be rendered from the start.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBcpD.png)

Comment: Please provide  Minimal, Reproducible Example of your code.

Comment: Hey, What do you mean by displaying all the products in a form? Is that a from or a table? Let's say we select one product from the list, then it is possible to show that product data in a form.

Comment: ive edited the original post, i hope it is now much apropiate and understandable

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.List) are a bit short on explanation for the `Form.List`, and since a code sample is worth a thousand words...

This renders the dynamic form list with one item already visible:

```
const initialValues = {
  users: [
    { age: undefined } // undefined will render the placeholder
  ] 
};

<Form initialValues={initialValues}>
  <Form.List name="users">
    {(fields, { add }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          {fields.map(field => (
            <Row key={field.key}>
              <Col>
                <Form.Item
                  placeholder="age"
                  name={[field.age, 'age']}
                >
                  <Input />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Form.Item
                  placeholder="sex"
                  name={[field.sex, 'sex']}
                >
                  <Input />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Form.Item
                  placeholder="name"
                  name={[field.name, 'name']}
                >
                  <Input />
                </Form.Item>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          ))}
          <button onClick={() => add()}>Add</button>
        </div> 
      )
    }}
  </Form.List>
</Form>
```

Comment: Watch out!
`<button onClick={add}>Add</button>`
will cause the following error:
`index.js:1 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property...`

It needs to be `<button onClick={() => add()}>Add</button>`

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using `initialValues` prop of Form.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-turing-g8ft6?file=/index.js 
Docs: https://ant.design/components/form/#API